# git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'. git problem

Tags: git

I get this error when I try to pull, clone or push something from local files. I tryed to solve using the following methods:

> - Reupdating path variable to C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
> - Reinstalled latest version of Git
> - git exec path give me the correct %path% variable
> - tried with http method instead of https

```
git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git2/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
credential.helper=manager
difftool.sourcetree.cmd='' "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
mergetool.sourcetree.cmd=''
mergetool.sourcetree.trustexitcode=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
```

Comment: Can you add the exact command you are running, as well at the error you are getting? Also, the output of `git config --list` could help.

Comment: yes, i can. Here the config

Comment: It seems to be a Windows configuration issue. I'm not familiar with Windows. Maybe one of these can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366101/git-remote-https-is-not-a-git-command https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099023/remote-https-is-not-a-git-command-when-cloning-repo

Comment: i tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it may be an issue with your installation of GitHub Desktop. Have you tried reinstalling GitHub Desktop again? If not, I would recommend deleting the following two directories to allow you to perform a fresh installation:

%AppData%\GitHubDesktop
%LocalAppData%\GitHubDesktop

Then install GitHub Desktop again and see if you are able to perform a clone operation successfully.

Comment: i didn't install github desktop. Just git. I was trying to clone from chrome, however same problem

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I had a wrong path variable. It was "GIT_EXEC_PATH" wich was pointing to a wrong exe file. To fix just delete it and recreate

Answer (score 0):

Check your environment variables once, if they are not added properly, delete them. Git folder is always or by default in C drive. if you have changed it to another drive, go to that respective drive and find Git folder and copy git/cmd path and git/bin path and add it to the path of the environment variables. after this, restart the command prompt or powershell. whatever you're using.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).